# PHP insert gives me undefined index?

Tags: php, mysql

So i'm trying to insert values in my database, it worked in register and i copy and pasted the same code but when i changed the values it won't insert although var dump gives me value, the query keeps on giving me a false one;

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST">
 <fieldset>
<legend>Account Register</legend>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="PID" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Product ID</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="iPID" name="inputpid" placeholder="Product ID" type="text" required>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Pname" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Product Name</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="iPname" name="inputpname" placeholder="Product Name" type="text" required>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Pprice" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Product Price</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="iPprice" name="inputpprice" placeholder="Product Price" type="text" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the php code below this form; I already have ob_start and session_start at the top of the codes;

```
<?php
 include("config.php");
 $ppid=$_POST['inputpid'];
 $pname=$_POST['inputpname'];
 $pprice=$_POST['inputpprice'];

 $product_query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tblproducts(p_pid, p_name, p_price) VALUES('$ppid', '$pname', $pprice')");

 var_dump($ppid);
 var_dump($pname);
 var_dump($pprice);
 var_dump($product_query);
?>
```

I don't know what i'm missing in this one and hope someone could help me with this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$pprice'` seems to be missing an opening quote

Comment: Besides the fact, that you shouldn't use post data directly in your query, you are missing a single quote before `$pprice` in the insert query. use `mysqli_error()` to display the error message from SQL.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And your'e getting FALSE because you have syntax errors in your query, and coded on the assumption that queries never fail. That's exactly the WRONG attitude to have. never assume success. always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Thanks guys, that was really weird. Earlier i'm pretty sure there's a single quote on the previous version before i modified it. Phew, glad it worked now. Thank you for the tips!

Comment: @Sync Hey, Adarsh definitely beat me to the answer, but you should still try out the filter and safe escape in my answer; it's simple to add in and may save you some trouble in the future.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

In response to @tadman's comment on this answer, here is the proper way to insert the record using a parameterized query. I used the procedural functions instead of the object-oriented style to keep the format similar to the code in the question.

```
<?php
 include("config.php");
 $filtered = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO tblproducts(p_pid, p_name, p_price) VALUES(?, ?, ?)');
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $filtered['inputpid'], $filtered['inputpname'], $filtered['inputpprice']); // 's' for string, 'i' for integer, 'd' for double, 'b' for blob

 $product_query = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

 var_dump($filtered['inputpid']);
 var_dump($filtered['inputpname']);
 var_dump($filtered['inputpprice']);
 var_dump($product_query);
?>
```

And for anyone interested in the object-oriented method for doing the same thing:

```
<?php
 include('config.php');
 $filtered = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

 $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO tblproducts(p_pid, p_name, p_price) VALUES(?, ?, ?)');
 $stmt->bind_param('sss', $filtered['inputpid'], $filtered['inputpname'], $filtered['inputpprice']);
 $product_query = $stmt->execute();

 var_dump($filtered, $product_query);
?>
```

**Previous**

I agree with several of the comments above that you're vulnerable to SQL injection with the code you posted. The code below will correct the syntax error you had in your original query and it'll also clean the input and safely escape it for insertion in your database table.

```
<?php
 include("config.php");
 $filtered = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
 $ppid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $filtered['inputpid']);
 $pname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $filtered['inputpname']);
 $pprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $filtered['inputpprice']);

 $product_query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tblproducts(p_pid, p_name, p_price) VALUES($ppid, $pname, $pprice)");

 var_dump($ppid);
 var_dump($pname);
 var_dump($pprice);
 var_dump($product_query);
?>
```

Comment: Prepared queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) is the answer here. Manually escaping things is ridiculous, messy, and error-prone.

Comment: @tadman I agree, but the simplest example for the OP to learn from was to use mysqli as the method.

Comment: This encourages dangerous habits out of the gate. Missing even one of those escapes creates a massive SQL injection hole. Using parameterized queries is not hard, and avoids confusion over how and when to escape. I have no idea how this is "simpler" than a `bind_param` example, as one done that way has way less clutter and could be just two lines vs. five.

Comment: Thanks. That looks considerably better. Using the object-oriented notation cleans things up even more, but as you note that's an artifact of the question. I'd strongly encourage people to use that style whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
$product_query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tblproducts(p_pid, p_name, p_price) VALUES('$ppid', '$pname', '$pprice')");
```

please put $pprice in singlequots